# Need same underline via css on active tab like on tabs on hover

Tags: html, css

I need to make the same underline on active tabs(Domov), like on other, when you hover the mouse. Because border-bottom makes a border that is lower then hover, underlines look in here- https://vitas.sk/1/ (try to move mouse on tabs to see the problem).
- Yes, pictures are not optimized, because its just test page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In view of Juraj's comments, I amend my proposal:) 
On .sliding-middle-out:after selector, you can add:

```
position: relative;
top: 6px;
```

(because there are padding-bottom: 3px; on sliding-middle-out class)

Comment: Yes I also forgot to say to remove the margin: auto.

Oh yes, you can just remove the padding-bottom on sliding-middle-out (I thought he was mandatory :D)

Comment: Wait that position absolute destroys my effect. I need auto margin, so problem is still there and removing padding doesnt help without position absolute. (with position absolute the line goes from left to right. Without its goes from middle to sides.)

Comment: And i need effect to go from middle to sides.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't know that.

May be : position : relative; top:6px ?